# jQuery DOM node with additional selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to do additional selections after I pass in a DOM node in jQuery.  In this example, I'm trying to show a "hidden" submit button after a change in the select box (notice, I'm passing in the FORM element, NOT the SELECT element:

```
<form id="UpdateRegistrationStatusForm">
   <select id="registration_status" onchange="AdjustRegistrationStatus(this.form)">
         <option value="1">approved</option>
         <option value="2">cancelled</option>
   </select>
   <input id="registration_status_update" type="submit" style="display:none" value="update"/>
</form>
```

So, the jQuery code that *I WANT TO DO, BUT DOESN'T WORK* looks something like this...

```
function AdjustRegistrationStatus(myForm)
{
     jQuery(myForm "#registration_status_update").show();
     if (jQuery(myForm "#registration_status").val() == 1)
     {
          //do some other things here...
     }
}
```

I want to start with a FORM DOM object and add additional "string" selectors.  Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for the [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function, but I'm a bit confused because the subordinate elements have IDs, so you don't really need to start with the form. If they had some other, non-unique thing (like a class) you might do this:

```
var form = $('#UpdateRegistrationStatusForm');
form.find('.regupdate').show();
if (form.find('.regstatus').val() == 1)
{
    //...
}
```

..but with IDs there's not much reason to.

Answer (score 1):

For this, use an [`#id` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (an `id` should be unique, doesn't matter what it's relative to):

```
jQuery("#registration_status_update").show();
```

In *other cases*, use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) like this:

```
jQuery("#registration_status_update").show();
```

[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) finds all descendants matching the selector, [it's one of many tree traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) used for moving around.